# Suse Studio Gnome Desktop not showing

Tags: suse

I made a custom distro with Suse Studio and I booted it with test drive, I am not booted into a Desktop but rather a "Activities" page, how do I boot up the Desktop so I can see icons and everything? Windowing system is Gnome, I see Desktop folder when I use the ls command, but I cannot get into the GUI of it. Can someone help me?

Comment: I boot into Activities Page, not Desktop basically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all gnome Packages to your OS and remove confilct Packages from it and try again
If it didnot work try to change desktop settings